# WooCommerce : Adding fee based on the cart total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add fee based on the cart total. But the fee adds on `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`. But I don't know how to make it based on cart total. When the updated or deleted, the total change, so I am unable to get proper total and add fee.

```
function woo_add_cart_fee() {
    $cart_total = ;
    $fee = (int)$cart_total*5/100;
    WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Credits :', $fee, false, '' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

This is my code. I am unable to find the way. Can anyone help.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to add a fee based on cart total?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function woo_dm_add_custom_fees(){
    $cart_total = 0;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ){ 
        $cart_total += $item["line_total"];
    }
    $fee = (int)$cart_total*5/100;
    WC()->cart->add_fee( "Credits :", $fee, false, '' );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'woo_dm_add_custom_fees' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 'woo_dm_add_custom_fees' );
```

Comment: Oh cool.! Can I get the tax applied total.? Like the total that has applied with tax and shipping.? I will calculate it later with `$cart_total*5/100` currently i get only cart sub total.!

Comment: Have not tried but you can use **get_line_total( $item, true, true );** to get the sub total instead. Shipping is always added later I think. Check this for details: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html